# httpd.config error when insntalling mod_wsgi+django

Tags: apache

its been more than 2 weeks. i try to instal but still getting error. 
firstly, indeed I have searched similar error but i didn't find solution at all. if you find it. please let me know.

second, this is my state :
1. i have installed python 2.7 and django 1.5.1 (it works).
2. i also install MAMP.
3. i try to configure mod_wsgi and want it integrated with my MAMP apache server.
4. using mac mountain lion 10.8.4

my configuration file :

1. /etc/apache2/original/extra/httpd-userdir.conf [inside my apache2/original/extra/](http://pastebin.com/7y7ibuqP)
2. /etc/apache2/users/akhyar.conf pastebin.com/zcY58WTV (sorry about this Iam new on stack overflow)
3. /etc/apache2/httpd.conf pastebin.com/je2D8zMz

third, this is my error :
when i run apachectl configtest this error appears [my error](http://pastebin.com/ZdrWqZJz)
so, what is going on actually? can someone tell me why and show me the mistakes?
if its been solved, what is the next step for configuring mod_wsgi on my MAMP?

thanks before, any help are highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that this is purely an apache conf error, gonna remove the django/python/mod-wsgi tags. Also, for things like this, the Apache version number is very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this file, line 15, you're including the per-user conf files:

http://pastebin.com/7y7ibuqP

On line 473 of this one, one of those per-user conf files, you're including the above file again:

http://pastebin.com/zcY58WTV

This causes infinite recursion while trying to parse the conf files.

I think there are some other errors too, and to be honest the files are pretty messy, but the best way forward is to remove *all* Include directives from akhyar.conf. For the most part they're already duplicates, where they're not, inline the contents of those files instead of using `Include`. If there are other errors, you'll at least see useful line numbers to start tracking them down.

Also note that the `[warn]` lines are just warnings - which you should probably fix, but the server will still run without them, that's not what's causing the error.

Comment: thanks in advance. this is my result after deleting user directives [link](http://pastebin.com/8r6L0LJu) . did the problem has been all solved ? is there user problem issue on next time because of I removes the user directives?
Iam new on this. I even dont know whether this is apache default from mac or my MAMP.

Comment: Well... there's probably still problems :D but try running `sudo apachectl stop` then `sudo apachectl start`, and if you don't see a scary-looking error message, try opening it in your web browser. I think it's pretty likely that you'll get an error either when restarting or in the browser, but that error message should point you to you next step.

Comment: I got 403 forbidden page when i try to open localhost. 
is this default apache from mac? how do i know?

Comment: Easy way is to run `sudo apachectl stop`, then try to open it again. If you can't get to the 403, then it must be from your apache. But at this point, please start with the 403 for debugging further and open a new question if google/etc doesn't suffice - the original error you had was from infinite recursion, the 403 will be from something unrelated.